# New Placeholder Issue in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, placeholder

I found a way to make the placeholder attribute in IE9 but there is a little problem. As soon I click on the text box the placeholder text disappears. I wanted to have the functionality like twitter.com/signup has in IE. 
Here is the code which made the Placeholder work in IE9.

http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/placeholder-support/

Comment: Just to clarify: Does the code you linked to work or not work in IE9?

Comment: Seems to require jQuery, are you using that? If so, perhaps use a jQuery tag on the question? Placeholders are much misused to the extent that they are a great annoyance, consider very carefully whether you should be modifying the browser's default behaviour when focusing on an input.